# how to handle different structures with a single c++ class member?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I am having a c++ class, A provision should be given to User to input different kinds of custom structures ex:

```
struct user1 {
        int var1;
        char var2;
};

struct user2 {
    vector<int> vecArr(5);
};

class node {
    // need store a structure obj here.
};

int main() {
  vector<class node> node_data;
}
```

the class is supposed to store the structures of above types, one per instance of class object. how to create a generic class that can handle different type of structures? Any directions towards the solutions will be appriciated.

*senario: Once the structure used to create instance of class, its not changed. each class object will have only one structure. cannot use boost because of restrictions*

Thanks,
Vivek.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Boost.Variant.

Comment: or `std::variant` for C++17

Comment: maybe a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). you could use variant, but maybe something much simpler will do the job. A `char` is also just a number, and a vector doesnt care too much whether it holds 2 or 5 elements. What do you want to do with that structures?

Comment: btw c++ does not have classes and structures. c++ has classes that you can declare with the keyword `class` or with the keyword `struct`

Comment: @user463035818: the structure is basically a user defined data, which will be stored in a vector of class objects, this needs the get and set functions as well.

Comment: can you give a short example of usage?

Comment: @user463035818 and classes declared with the keyword `union`, but those have a different semantic

Comment: Why can't you inherit all the classes from a common interface?

Comment: Are the classes supplied at compile-time or run-time? Will `node_data` hold only 1 kind of `node`, or different ones (different underlying struct)?

Comment: @super: hi, classes will be supplied run-time. and node_data will hold 1 kid of node. there may be another like "node_data_2" which will might handle different node data. Thanks.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka: Hi, didnt get your suggestion,will you please eloborate.